# How to Detect Collision with every child in a Parent in Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movie Clip and in that movie clip there are a few more movie Clips (rectangle)...how do i detect collision with all those rectangles without having to write code for every single one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over any DisplayObjectContainer's children like this:

```
for( var i:int = 0; i < clip.numChildren; i++) 
    doStuffWith( clip.getChildAt(i) );
```

To test collision with any child object, you could use this:

```
function hitTestChildren( target:DisplayObject, parent:DisplayObjectContainer ):Boolean {
    for( var i:int = 0; i< parent.numChildren; i++)
        if( target.hitTestObject( parent.getChildAt(i))) return true;
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

After looking at the source FLA, here's how to include collisions for your gravity simulation:

```
function hitTestY( target:DisplayObject, container:DisplayObjectContainer ):Number {
    //iterate over all the child objects of the container (i.e. the "parent")
    for( var i:int = 0; i< container.numChildren; i++) {
        var mc:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(i)
        // Test for collisions
        // There were some glitches with Shapes, so we only test Sprites and MovieClips 
        if( mc is Sprite && target.hitTestObject( mc )) 
            // return the global y-coordinate (relative to the stage) of the object that was hit
            return container.localToGlobal( new Point(mc.x, mc.y ) ).y;
    }
    // if nothing was hit, just return the target's original y-coordinate
    return target.y;
}

function onEnter(evt:Event):void {
    vy +=  ay;
    vx +=  ax;
    vx *=  friction;
    vy *=  friction;
    ball.x +=  vx;
    ball.y +=  vy;
    ball.y = hitTestY( ball, platform_mc);
}
```

You'll have to modify your rectangle objects so that their respective origins are at 0,0 instead of in the middle of the shape, though.

**END EDIT**

However, if you are not dealing with simple, rectangular shapes, but complex shapes or transparencies, you might want to use a different approach:  You can draw any combination of shapes to a bitmap, and then use `BitmapData#hitTest` to see if they intersect (in this case, you'd do that with the entire`parent` containing all children and the `target` clip itself, but not with the individual children).

I won't post any code (it is longish), but there is a nice and clean example of how to do this on [Mike Chambers' blog](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/).